# Handling CORS when developing from localhost using REST APIs - Streamlabs API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I'm sure this question will get flagged in some manner, however hours of searching has prompted no usable information.

Many projects require me to use various APIs. The current project uses the Twitch and Streamlabs API. When trying to access the /authorize endpoints, I'm hit with a CORS policy restriction. This is because my referer/origin is localhost.

[image: CORS origin policy]

My question lies in how others set up their environment for this not to be an issue. I understand why CORS is blocking me (to an extent), but what I don't understand is how I'm expected to work away from my production server if `localhost` has a blanket restriction.

I have as well tried manipulating headers in fetch as well as using `[no-cors]`, but no avail here either. Any ideas?

```
  // Starts authorization
  getAuth() {
    const data = fetch (`https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/authorize?client_id=${clientID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitchinstudios.com&scope=donations.create%20donations.read%20alerts.write`, {
    headers: {
      "Origin" : "https://twitchinstudios.com",
      "Referer" : "https://twitchinstudios.com"
    },   
    mode: 'no-cors'});
    const code = data.json.code;
    console.log(code);

  // Post to /token endpoint
  const tokenCall = fetch (`https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/token?grant_type=authorization_token&client_id=knOhuT74QrSn8h1m8tU8ucrFfVIfUuVpll71ErbI&client_secret=${clientSecret}&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitchinstudios.com&code=${code}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors'
  })
```

Here is the documentation for their API as well: https://dev.streamlabs.com/reference

Comment: `This is because my referer/origin is localhost` - I take it this is a "Twitch and Streamlabs API" restriction, as there's no "blanket ban" on localhost regarding CORS - I gather "Twitch and Streamlabs API" do work if host is not localhost?

Comment: Which Browser are you using? Chrome? If so, localhost POST requests are an outstanding bug since 2010. There's the report (and some workarounds) [**here**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743).

Comment: Are you sure `streamlabs.com` issue CORS headers? Because I don't think this issue is anything to do with the fact that the host is localhost

Comment: @obsidian I am using Chrome, but tested with Firefox to be sure as well.

Comment: @jaromanda correct yes, and my wording may be incorrect in saying a blanket ban, but in my experiences this has been pretty typical and I've not found a non-messy way to handle this when developing/testing.

Comment: @jaromanda I do not see any, no.

Comment: In that case the issue is nothing at all to do with localhost - `streamlabs.com` simply doesn't allow you to borrow its resources like that

Comment: @jaromanda how do you mean? In what way should it be handled if I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Here is the documentation for their API as well: https://dev.streamlabs.com/reference

Comment: Nothing in that documentation suggests you can use the api from a web page

Comment: Dumb it down for me? What other use cases are they implying?

Comment: API access from a server (hence, **curl** in the examples)

Comment: You are correct, and I was able to resolve this and figure out the gap in my understanding, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a CORS issue, nor an API issue. It was an issue in my understanding.

For anyone stumbling upon this, check for any Allow-Access headers being passed, and if none are being passed, you're not meant to access it from the web page level.

Instead, allowing my node server to handle the request allowed me access.